# How to launch the "Run Result Viewer" and open the XML result file programmatically (in c#)

Tags: c#, qtp, hp-uft, test-results

If I can launch the UFT and run a test by means of "QTObjectModelLib", there might be a proper application class or another library for "Run Result Viewer" application around the corner to open the result xml file.

In general I want to launch another app from my C# app and feed a file into to be opened. Maybe we can do that without any proprietry application class with common .net classes.

I tried "ProcessStartInfo" as following, but no success:

```
ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo();
 start.Arguments = @"...\Results.xml";
 start.FileName = @"....\QTReport.exe";
 using (Process ResultViewerProc = Process.Start(start))
 {
    start.WaitForExit();
 }
```

Comment: I looked into this some time ago but wasn't able to find a solution. At the time I wrote a parser for QTP 'results xml' file which essentially produced a custom report based on the xml

Comment: @Zac did you look for any possible XSLT given by QTP anyhow!?